# Python: Pandas to add a string if the condition is NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change is the name column is NaN, I want to add a string 'P' if there is a dash in column symbol.

```
      name    symbol
0     NaN     Bom
1     John    Madam-T
2     Marry   Madam
3     NaN     Madam-T 
4     NaN     Bom-T
5     NaN     Marry-Y
```

The desired outcome is

```
      name    symbol
0     NaN     Bom
1     John    Madam-T
2     Marry   Madam
3     NaN     Madam-PT 
4     NaN     Bom-PT
5     NaN     Marry-PY
```

Index 3 to 5 will add a string of P as it contains -
But I only want it to occurred if the condition of the column name is NaN.
`df = df['symbol'].str.replace('-', '-P')` replace all columns that contains -
`df = df['name'].isnull` call the NaN in column name
however, I unable to combine both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select and set values filterd by mask:

```
m = df['name'].isnull()
df.loc[m, 'symbol'] = df.loc[m, 'symbol'].str.replace('-', '-P')
print (df)
    name    symbol
0    NaN       Bom
1   John   Madam-T
2  Marry     Madam
3    NaN  Madam-PT
4    NaN    Bom-PT
5    NaN  Marry-PY
```